# How do I coordinate versioned signature blocks with an article?

Tags: 7, users, nodes

I have users who write articles and need to show the appropriate bio content when viewing their published page.

I could add the signature field to their user account, however, I need this info to be version aware so that previous published pages are not affected by revised bios.

For example:

- An article published between 2010-2012 uses the User's bio #1
- An article published in 2013+ uses signature bio #2 and so
  on

How do I make the joins needed to go from article->userid->user's appropriate bio node?

I've tried entity prepopulate, but it can't automatically lookup and embed the user's latest bio node as a hidden field in an a new article.

Basically, I just want someway to look up another content type made by this user and automatically tie it to the article he's creating.

How do you handle that process?